# When a socket switch to TIME_WAIT state, why I can't see its inode number?

Tags: tcp, linux-networking, kernel, socket

I'm developing a program in python that parses `/proc/net/tcp` informations, but unfortunately, while I was doing this, I saw a strange thing.

Practically, when a socket change in `TIME_WAIT` state, losses its inode number, and I don't know who is the owner of this socket.

I read some documents about this `TIME_WAIT` issue, and I understood that the connection is practically finished, and it remain in wait only to guarantee the data transfer.

Someone knows something about it?

Comment: Sockets don't change to TIME_WAIT state, connections (or endpoints) do.

Comment: You can see this quite nicely if you run `watch -n 0.1 'netstat -ae'`, open a connection (as unprivileged user) to anywhere and close it again. You will see, that the inode number switches to 0 and user is set to root, immediately after closing the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the socket is in [TIME_WAIT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1323#appendix-B), there is no process attached to it anymore and the kernel is just holding it in case some other packet arrives. At this point, the software the originally opened this socket does not have a open file description to it anymore. That's why you can't find any relation to it. The socket that existed in /proc/$PID/fd is not there anymore.

Answer (score 2):

A socket in `TIME_WAIT` status is no longer owned by a process, but by the kernel. As such, there *is* no owner, that's why you can't see it :)